# Change foundation icon when clicked

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to figure out how to change the icon of button when clicked.

```
<div class="row">
    <a class="slideout-button"><i class="general foundicon-left-arrow"></i
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to change to "foundicon-right-arrow" when the slider is open.

Do you guys know how?

Comment: What have you tried? **Click events** usually require javascript. Is that sort of solution what you are after?

Comment: Are you already including jQuery? It would be pretty simple to do a little class change on a click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you just need to rotate your icon and not replaced him with css rotate:

```
 .slideout-button.open i:before{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

And jQuery code:

```
$(".slideout-button").on('click', function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `<button>` instead of `<a>` in your case.

```
<button class="slideout-button"><i class="general foundicon-left-arrow"></i
</button>
```

You can use jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".slideout-button").click(function(){
      $(".slideout-button i").removeClass("foundicon-left-arrow").addClass("foundicon-right-arrow");
   });

});
```